# Excessive usage of MySQL Views

Tags: mysql, view

Recently discovered the convenience of using MySQL Views to accumulate data for presentation. I found it convenient because for tables having referential integrity (foreign keys) can be resolved right from the database. For instance, a table of `Users` with a foreign key `role_id` will be resolved to have the actual role's name as well from maybe the `Roles` table instead of just the `role_id` which essentially makes no meaning to the viewer.

I am starting to get used to this and already having a lot of views already and therefore having the fear that if I use them too much I might get into some unforeseen issues. Can anyone throw some light into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > *"There are no restrictions within MySQL, so in theory it's only the 
> >     restrictions of your operating system that apply. But they are usually 
> >     high enough not to be relevant for practical uses."*

In reference to the article on mysql forum:
[***MySQL Forums :: Views :: Maximum number of views (resolved: no max)***](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,215704,215909#msg-215909)

Answer (score 1):

Views are basically prepared server-side `SELECT` statements. If you try to avoid the views you're using, you'll find yourself doing the same queries explicitly in your application, which won't be more effective than using the prepared views on the server.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but are there known issues or violation of any best practices if i continue to use them in large numbers